# Antd inputNumber отключение ввода в поле с клавиатуры (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design

Всем привет! Подскажите плз, есть ли способ заблокировать текстовое поле inputNumber (antd) для ввода с клавиатуры и оставить только ввод с помощью кнопок.

[image: Пример инпута]

В api antd встроенных средств для реализации не нашел. Пробывал только на onChange повесить такой обработчик, но остается возможность удаления:

```
const handleChange = (value) => value.slice(0, value.length - 1);
```

Comment: а зачем тогда инпут; сделайте кнопки и текст рядом

Comment: нашел такой вариант     const input: any = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isTableFormat && input.current) {
            input.current.input.setAttribute('readonly', 'true');
        }
    });